# Modified Double Slits: 2 Sources

Tags: double-slit-experiment

Setup:
2 identical electron guns capable of firing 1 electron each time, 2 slits, 2 detectors which will lit up when something passes through one of the slit. Both guns to fire at the same time throughout the experiment.

I am wondering since I can't tell which electrons came from which sources, would there be an interference pattern? Note I'm not erasing anything like the quantum eraser experiment. Also what about the same setup but 1 detector is used instead?

Comment: Your question is too ambiguous. Please clarify the relative positions of the guns, slits and detectors. Are you saying that the detectors are monitoring which slit each electron passes through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of electrons, your thought experiment is complicated by electrostatic repulsion between the two particles. In order to keep things simple, in the following answer I'll ignore electric charge, so it applies only to a different version of your experiment, performed with two non-interacting fermions. I'll address only the case in which they pass through different slits and are detected. I know that this is only part of your question. I'm sorry. If I'll find the time, I'll try to extend the consideration.

---

### Single particle review

As an introduction, let's review how the interference pattern is produced by a single particle.

Let's say that the wavefunction of a particle found to be near slit 1 or slit 2 is $\psi_1(\vec{x})$ or $\psi_2(\vec{x})$ respectively. These two wavefunctions are sharply localized near the respective slits. If we don't observe which slit the particle went through, the state of the particle is $$\psi(\vec{x}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \Bigl(\psi_1(\vec{x}) + \psi_2(\vec{x}) \Bigr)$$

After some time, the wavefunctions evolve (the particle "moves", or "propagates"):
$$\psi_1(\vec{x}) \rightarrow \psi_1(\vec{x},t) , \qquad \psi_2(\vec{x}) \rightarrow \psi_2(\vec{x},t),$$
so that the state of the particle becomes: $$\psi(\vec{x},t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \Bigl(\psi_1(\vec{x},t) + \psi_2(\vec{x},t) \Bigr).$$

Now we want to calculate the particle density $\rho(\vec{x}_0)$, which in the single particle case is the same as the probability distribution of finding the particle at spot $\vec{x}_0$. It is given by the following integral, where $\delta$ is Dirac's delta distribution:
$$ \rho(\vec{x}_0) = \int \psi^\dagger(\vec{x},t) \delta(\vec{x} - \vec{x}_0) \psi(\vec{x},t) \mathrm{d}_3x = \left| \psi(\vec{x}_0,t) \right|^2 = \frac{1}{2} \left( \left| \psi_1(\vec{x}_0,t) \right|^2 + \left| \psi_2(\vec{x}_0,t) \right|^2 + 2 \Re \left( \psi_1^\dagger(\vec{x}_0,t) \psi_2(\vec{x}_0,t) \right) \right),$$
where $\Re$ is the real part. It is clear that $\left|\psi_1(\vec{x}_0,t) \right|^2$ is the distribution we would get if the particle was observed to pass through slit 1 (and similarly for $\left|\psi_2(\vec{x}_0,t) \right|^2$), so the interference pattern is given by the term $2\Re \left( \psi_1^\dagger(\vec{x}_0,t) \psi_2(\vec{x}_0,t) \right)$.

---

### Two particles

Now we can consider the case of your experiment with two non-interacting fermions.

Let's suppose that the two detectors lit up at the same time, so that one particle is in state $\psi_1$, and the other one is in state $\psi_2$. Since the two particles are indistinguishable fermions, the state of the system must be a superposition anti-symmetric with respect to exchange of the particles:
$$\psi(\vec{x}_1,\vec{x}_2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \Bigl( \psi_1(\vec{x}_1)\psi_2(\vec{x}_2) - \psi_1(\vec{x}_2)\psi_2(\vec{x}_1) \Bigr).$$

After some time, the wavefunction evolve:
$$\psi(\vec{x}_1,\vec{x}_2,t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \Bigl( \psi_1(\vec{x}_1,t)\psi_2(\vec{x}_2,t) - \psi_1(\vec{x}_2,t)\psi_2(\vec{x}_1,t) \Bigr).$$
(Note: This evolution would be different for charged particles like electrons, because electrostatic repulsion would make the two electrons entangled).

Now we want to calculate the particle density $\rho(\vec{x}_0)$ in point $\vec{x}_0$ (its integral over the whole space this time is $2$ because the particles are two, so $\rho$ strictly speaking is not a probability, even if it tells us where the particles are more or less probable to be found). If for one particle the relevant projector was $\delta(\vec{x} - \vec{x}_0)$, now that we have two particles the projector is $\delta(\vec{x}_1 - \vec{x}_0) + \delta(\vec{x}_2 - \vec{x}_0)$. Then we get:
$$\rho(\vec{x}_0) = \int \psi^\dagger(\vec{x}_1,\vec{x}_2,t) \Bigl[ \delta(\vec{x}_1-\vec{x}_0) + \delta(\vec{x}_2-\vec{x}_0) \Bigr] \psi(\vec{x}_1,\vec{x}_2,t) \mathrm{d}_3x_1\mathrm{d}_3x_2 = \int \left|\psi(\vec{x}_0,\vec{x}_2,t)\right|^2 \mathrm{d}_3x_2 + \int \left|\psi(\vec{x}_1,\vec{x}_0,t)\right|^2 \mathrm{d}_3x_1 = 2 \int \left|\psi(\vec{x},\vec{x}_0,t)\right|^2 \mathrm{d}_3x$$

Let's calculate $\left|\psi(\vec{x},\vec{x}_0,t)\right|^2$:
$$\left|\psi(\vec{x},\vec{x}_0,t)\right|^2 = \frac{1}{2} \left[ \left|\psi_1(\vec{x}_0,t)\right|^2 \left|\psi_2(\vec{x},t)\right|^2 + \left|\psi_2(\vec{x}_0,t)\right|^2 \left|\psi_1(\vec{x},t)\right|^2 - 2 \Re\left( \psi_1(\vec{x}_0,t)\psi_2^\dagger(\vec{x}_0,t)\psi_1^\dagger(\vec{x},t)\psi_2(\vec{x},t) \right) \right].$$

And now we substitute it into $\rho(\vec{x}_0)$ and get:
$$\rho(\vec{x}_0) = 2 \int \left|\psi(\vec{x},\vec{x}_0,t)\right|^2 \mathrm{d}_3x = \left|\psi_1(\vec{x}_0,t)\right|^2 + \left|\psi_2(\vec{x}_0,t)\right|^2 - 2 \Re\left( \psi_1(\vec{x}_0,t)\psi_2^\dagger(\vec{x}_0,t) \int \psi_1^\dagger(\vec{x},t)\psi_2(\vec{x},t) \mathrm{d}_3x \right).$$

The interference pattern is obviously given by the third term, the real part. Let's study this term. Its main feature is the integral $\int \psi_1^\dagger(\vec{x},t)\psi_2(\vec{x},t) \mathrm{d}_3x$, that is the inner product of $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ at time $t$. Since time evolution is unitary, inner products are conserved through time, and therefore this integral is the same as if it was calculated at time $t=0$. But at $t=0$, $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ were localized, so they had disjoint supports and the integral was zero. Then we conclude that the third term is *zero* and obtain simply
$$\rho(\vec{x}_0) = \left|\psi_1(\vec{x}_0,t)\right|^2 + \left|\psi_2(\vec{x}_0,t)\right|^2.$$

**TL;DNR**: The answer is no, we don't observe an interference pattern, because when the two particles pass through the slits they are distinguishable in the sense that they are in separated space regions.